# Azure DevOps Dashboard Created By Created Date

Tags: azure-devops, dashboard

I've been asked to generate a report listing all the dashboards used by a team, who created them and when.  Anyone know how to get this information from Azure DevOps?  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately we cannot get the history information for now.

We can get the list of dashboards for a specific team by calling the REST API ([Dashboards - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/dashboard/dashboards/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1)), and retrieve the properties (detail information) for a specific dashborad ([Dashboards - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/dashboard/dashboards/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1)), but both not include the history information (`Created By` and `Created Date` in your scenario).

There's already a [user voice submitted here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-azure-devops-formerly-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/9858555-add-activity-log-to-tfs-online-to-track-user-acces) to suggest the related feature with adding `Activity Log` to Azure DevOps (VSTS) to track user access, you can go and vote it up or submit a new user voice to suggest the feature to achieve that in future release...

Comment: Thank you for your response Andy.  I'll drop in on the user voice.